# ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Ayushi Sharma\attempt\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

Tags: flutter

- Error running Gradle:
  ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Ayushi Sharma\attempt\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Ayushi Sharma\attempt\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
  >   Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 5.1.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the
  >   distributionUrl in C:\Users\Ayushi Sharma\attempt\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to
  get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
  Command: C:\Users\Ayushi Sharma\attempt\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Need help!!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, In terminal using flutter clean command then build using flutter run and let me know what happens

Comment: ok sir, I'll tell u after doing it

Comment: Sir, after flutter clean, and again building the app using flutter run, it  is showing the same error...

Answer (score 0):

To resolve, change `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1` => `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2`, run flutter clean and try the build again.

According to the [Gradle_release_note](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/release-notes.html), the current (July 2019) version of the plugin and gradle are 3.4.2 and 5.1.1 respectively. I don't know if Flutter officially supports this version, although it seems to work on my project here and a clean build is markedly faster. The release notes cover some of the changes from 3.2.x => 3.3.x => 3.4.x.

To upgrade to the current version, edit `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` to source Gradle 5.1.1, and then you're able to upgrade the Gradle plugin to 3.4.2.

Note that once gradle 5.1.1 is being used, you can still set the plugin version back to 3.2.1 to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @AyushiSharma  if my answer helped you then feel free to accept the answer